# How do you turn hostile mobs against each other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been thinking of how to make a "mob war" map using the theory that owned projectiles can turn mobs against each other, along with shulkers being able to act as defense turrets for those on the same team. I have tried the `{ownerName}` tag on projectiles to turn non-shulker hostiles against each other, but to no avail. They appear to have no effect. Is this feature manipulable without plugins? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn a hostile or neutral (eg. not passive) mob against another by hitting it with a projectile that is "owned" by another mob:

1. Summon the mob that you want to get angry. This mob mush have specified a UUID:

   ```
   /summon <entityType> X Y Z {UUIDLeast:0L,UUIDMost:0L}
   ```

   Unfolded:

   ```
   /summon                      | summon  
   <entityType>                 | a <entityType> mob (eg. Zombie)
   X Y Z                        | at the coordinates X, Y, Z
   {UUIDLeast:0L,UUIDMost:0L}   | with an entity UUID "0-0-0-0-0"
   ```
2. Summon the mob you want to attack, and optionally add a custom name:

   ```
   /summon <entityType> X Y Z {CustomName:attacker}
   ```

   Unfolded:

   ```
   /summon                      | summon  
   <entityType>                 | a <entityType> mob (eg. Zombie)
   X Y Z                        | at the coordinates X, Y, Z
   {CustomName:attacker}        | named "attacker"
   ```
3. Get the latter spawned mob anger the first spawned one:

   ```
   /execute @e[name=attacker] ~ ~ ~ /summon Snowball ~ ~2.8 ~ {ownerName:"0-0-0-0-0"}
   ```

   Unfolded:

   ```
   /execute                   | for all 
   @e[name=attacker]          | entities named "attacker"   
   ~ ~ ~                      | at their coordinates 
   /summon                    | summon
   Snowball                   | a snowball
   ~ ~3 ~                     | 3 blocks above them  
   {ownerName:"0-0-0-0-0"}    | which is owned by the entity "0-0-0-0-0"
   ```

Comment: Have you tried this out? Ive tried it in a throwaway world, but I made the name "Tester" on a cow, with the {ownerName} tag to suit. Does the symbol-numeric format affect the way it works, or  does the height need to be at least 3 for it to work?

Comment: @FungusKing If you use the commands specified above is should work, I tested it. Just be aware of using the right letter case at names, and separating `ownerName` and `CustomName`, because the first works for entity selectors and the second for specifing projectile ownership (in this case). Also, the height of 3 is crucial for the mob to be hit. You can lower this value down to 2.8, but not further.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this as posted here: [How do I turn Passive mobs Hostile?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249798/how-do-i-turn-passive-mobs-hostile)

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"VillagerGolem",Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Fuse:32767,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}
```

It will make a Zombie being controlled  by a villager golem. To make it hurt things that it touches do this:

```
/execute @e[type=VillagerGolem] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[r=1] minecraft:instant_damage
```

Full credits to this answer to the person who answered on the linked post.

Comment: I think that it would be a bit of a kludge when the zombie dies, though. Thanks for the effort anyway. I was thinking from the "infighting" behaviour from when a skeleton shoots a hostile, or a llama spitting another llama.

Comment: Ok sorry (=. I dont have any idea how to do the others.